# How to fail Joi validation for empty/whitespace string?

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

I want Joi to reject strings like " " or "   ", how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Use `trim` and `min`:

```
const schema = Joi
  .string()
  .trim()
  .min(1)
  .required();
```

Tests:

```
console.log(schema.validate(' ')); // "value" is not allowed to be empty
console.log(schema.validate('')); // "value" is not allowed to be empty
console.log(schema.validate('  foo')); // value: 'foo'
console.log(schema.validate('foo  ')); // value: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use Case

Had a case for validating csv files (via Papa Parse), and a requirement for Joi to fail `trim()` validation verbosely. Normal behavior for `trim()` is to fix whitespace, which is sensible.

**We wanted a validation error via `trim()`, not autofix**.

### Example

##### Default

###### RESULT: no verbose error / passes validation / trims whitespace

```
const schema1 = Joi.object({ username: Joi.string().trim() })
const hasValidationError1 = schema1.validate({ username: ' aslezak ' })

// hasValidationError1 { value: { username: 'aslezak' } }
```

##### Override

###### RESULT: explicit verbose error / fails validation / require fix trim in csv and reprocess

```
const schema2 = Joi.object({ username: Joi.string().trim() })
const hasValidationError2 = schema2.validate(
{ username: ' aslezak ' },
{ abortEarly: false, convert: false, label: ['path', 'key', true] }
)

// hasValidationError2 = {
// value: { username: ' aslezak ' },
// error: { ValidationError: [ `"username" must not have leading or trailing whitespace.` ] },
// }
```

Referencing the `validate()` method in joi.dev docs was helpful for determining configuration options.

###### API Docs

https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#anyvalidatevalue-options

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here include unrelated details, hence replying.

All you need from Joi's default is to add `convert: false` inside `validate()` call. No trim is needed, no abort early or any other things.

```js
const result = Joi.validate("foo@example.com ", Joi.string().email(), {
   convert: false
});
```

Result:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "isJoi": true,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "\"value\" must be a valid email",
        "path": [],
        "type": "string.email",
        "context": {
          "value": "foo@example.com ",
          "label": "value"
        }
      }
    ],
    "_object": "foo@example.com "
  },
  "value": "foo@example.com "
}
```